# Why global var keep reseting inside my loop?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, global-variables

I'm working on a data science project and I need a loop to pass some values and save them to excel with the current date as index. What I did was a .py file defining some functions and one of them is:

```
timestamp = 0
def getTimestamp():
    global timestamp
    timestamp = int(client.get_server_time()['serverTime'])/1000
```

And imported the file as a module for my script:

```
from dataGet import *
...
while True:
    if Path(keys_path).is_file():
        if Path(port_path).is_file():
            #Command goes here!
            break
        else:
            #While loop to create portfolio df
            getTimestamp()
            holdings = {}
            while True:
                ticker = str(input('Pass ticker or type 0 to stop:\n'))
                if ticker == '0':
                    break
                elif len(ticker) <= 5:
                    try:
                        value = float(input('Pass your %s holdings:\n'%ticker))
                    except ValueError:
                        print('Value must be float or int.\n')
                    else:
                        holdings.update({ticker:value})
                else:
                    print('Value must have a maximum of 5 characters.\n')
            #Creates portfolio.xlsx file with portfolio df data
            df = pd.DataFrame(holdings,index=[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')])
            df.to_excel(port_path)
    else:
        ...
```

The problem is that the global variable 'timestamp' always reset and I end up with the index showing '1969/12/31' since the timestamp was reverted to 0.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance!

PS: The getTimestamp() function seems to work fine in other places where I don't use while loops.

Comment: Because you're calling `getTimestamp()` within the loop, which resets the global variable `timestamp` depending on what `client.get_server_time()` returns *each time it is called*.

Comment: Print the value returned by `client.get_server_time()['serverTime']` in `getTimestamp` to verify what it is returning.

Comment: It's not that it gets "reset", it's that your *imported version* is never updated. See the duplicate at the top.